# Incorrect flags for output/input in golang

Tags: go

Im having trouble getting my output file to create consistently for some reason. If I run the go file using `"./testtest -o testoutput.txt -i testinput.txt"` then it correctly creates a test file named "testoutput.txt."

But if I run the file using `"go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt"` (which is how my professor will test it) it will correctly display the console output, but will not write it to the text file.Here is my code to set the flags. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would GREATLY appreciate it. Few people at the Uni really seem very familiar with Go so I'm kinda spinning my wheels here trying to figure this out. THANK YOU!!

```
inputFile := flag.String("i", "input.txt", "Enter input file")
outputFile := flag.String("o", "team16_out_dis.txt", "Enter desired name for the output file")
flag.Parse()

openInputFile, err := os.Open(*inputFile)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error opening input file:", err)
return
}
defer func(inputFile *os.File) {
err := inputFile.Close()
if err != nil {
}
}(openInputFile)
```

I have tested if vs other flags and it seems identical but for some reason I can't get the output file to create using

Comment: `go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt` has an extra `.` (try `go run testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt` or `go run . -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt` ).

Comment: The "." after "run" is deliberate. It doesn't run otherwise

Comment: Then remove the `main.go` (`go run . -i ...`) or rename your source file to `main.go` (I'm guessing its called something else). To see what is happening add a `fmt.Println(os.Args)` in your app (this will output the command and params).

Comment: What do you mean remove main.go? I'm not following (Thank you for the help btw)

Comment: Sorry I meant `testtest.go` (most examples use `main.go`) - have added an answer that will, hopefully, clarify things.

Comment: The go run command looks like a cute thing but it is _incredibly_ hard to get it (really) right unless used in `go run .`, `go run <full/remote/import/path/NOT/some/local/filesystem/path>` and `go run mylittelehelper.go` where mylittlehelper.go ist a _single_ file package main wich is deliberately excluded from the build via a `//go:build ignore` directive.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of [`go run`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) is:

```
go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] package [arguments...]
```

To understands this we need the definition of "package":

> Typically the package is specified as a list of .go source files from a single
> directory, but it may also be an import path, file system path, or pattern
> matching a single known package, as in 'go run .' or 'go run my/cmd'.

So package can be one of:

- a list of .go source files from a single
  directory
- an import path, file system path, or pattern matching a single known package, as in 'go run .'

This makes things a bit confusing because `package` can be one argument or a list of `.go` files. `go run` works out where the spilt is by working through the arguments until it finds one that does not end with ".go" (simplifying a bit). If the first argument does not end with `.go` it will treat it as a "import path, file system..." and only process that one argument (everything following will be passed to your program as an argument).

Your command line is:

`go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt`

So the "package" is `.` and the arguments "testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt". You can see this by adding `fmt.Println(os.Args)` to your code; this will output something like:

```
[/tmp/go-build2893406250/b001/exe/temp3 testtest.go -i test -o test]
```

To get similar output using `go build` you would need to run:

```
go build
./testtest testtest.go -i test -o test
```

This is why your application is not behaving as expected; its failing to parse the command line arguments due to the unexpected `testtest.go` (and using the defaults). To fix this use either:

```
go run . -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt
```

or

```
go run testtest.go -i testinput.txt -o testoutput.txt
```

(this assumes that your source is in `testtest.go`).

If you want to see how `go run` works out where the command line arguments start see [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/cmd/go/internal/run/run.go;l=105).

**edit:** extra questions in comments below

> Is there EVER a case where you would run it as 1go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt etc..?1 or is that redundant and will always end up as an extra parameter?

The only situation would be if you want to pass `testtest.go` as an argument. The `flags` package assumes that flags come first and will stop processing when it finds something thats not a flag (you can use `flag.Args()` to get whatever is left after flags are removed).

As per [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax)

> Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".

So parsing will always stop at the `testtest.go` when running the command you supplied.

> Is there an easy way to account for the potentially erroneous extra parameter? Like can I use _ as a command line parameter the same way I would use it as a throw-away variable?

As mentioned above `flag` processes arguments until it hits something it does not recognise as a flag. The remaining arguments are available via [`flag.Args()`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Args) with the count accessible via [`flag.NArg`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Args). So if you want to check that `flag.Parse()` has consumed all arguments you can use:

```
flag.Parse()
if flag.NArg() != 0 {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected arguments: %v", flag.Args()))
}
```

Comment: So you're saying it's not a problem with the code itself but the way in which the code is being run?

Comment: Correct. This is one of the reasons you will frequently see recommendations to use `go build` rather than `go run`. Note that I have made some assumptions as you did not provide a [minimal, **reproducible**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Will make a small edit that may clarify things further.

Comment: Thank you, an MRE would be a little tricky to condense down to but I feel like you're probably correct. Is there EVER a case where you would run it as "go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt etc..?" or is that redundant and will always end up as an extra parameter? Is there an easy way to account for the potentially erroneous extra parameter? Like can I use _ as a command line parameter the same way I would use it as a throw-away variable? 
Just trying to understand, our program was the only one that threw this error apparently so either he typo'd ours on the run or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: See my edits (an MRE could have just output the value of `inputFile` and `outputFile`). I'd raise this with your professor; as per my examples the code runs and works when passed arguments in the expected format.

Comment: @LucasAustin "Is there EVER a case where you would run it as "go run . testtest.go -i testinput.txt etc..?" No as this is total _garbage_. You _never_ use filename arguments on go run! Unless you _know_ what you are doing. And even in that case you NEVER mix . and filename arguments. Newbies must use `go run .` _only_ or a plain `go build`.